# Remove all the blocks dragged by the user in Blockly

Tags: blockly, google-blockly

I am using Blockly library for a project. I want to remove all the blocks dragged by the user from the toolbox on pressing the reset button.

Can someone help with how can this be done. Which function do I have to use?

Answer (score 0):

This is implemented in Blockly by [fa279b9](https://github.com/google/blockly/commit/fa279b91cec68abcc1301bd41aa241cb0de23989). The user can do a context menu click on the workspace and select "Delete X Blocks" where X will be the number of blocks in the workspace:

[image: context menu showing 'delete 2 blocks' in a blockly workspace with 2 blocks that have been dragged into the workspace]